# How to hide files from Windows...on Mac OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems

I have created a FAT disk image using Disk Utility and added files to it. I would like to hide some of these files from Windows.  Is there a way to do this from OS X?

What I'm looking for is basically a Mac equivalent of [attrib](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true): a tool to set the Windows hidden attribute. Note that SetFile will *NOT* work, as it hides files from OS X, not Windows.

Comment: Setting the Hidden attribute isn't going to hide a file or folder from Windows. That attribute is only there to hide the file/folder in Explorer if it's set to hide them.

Answer (score 5):

Some `chmod` implementations allow the changing of MS-DOS permissions.

EDIT:
You can use [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/) to mount a volume in OS X to a directory, which may allow you to use the attrib command.

EDIT2: The Tcl '[file](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/mann/file.ntcl.html)' command might work from the command-line too.