# Making a file hidden in OS X but visible in Windows, and vice versa

Tags: windows, macos

My company makes a software program that runs on both Windows and Mac. While the main program executable and a few other files are different for the Windows version vs. the Mac version, the vast majority of the files are the same. I'd therefore like to be able to provide a single download that has all the files necessary for both Mac and Windows. But I'd like the Mac-only files to be hidden on Windows, and the Windows-only files to be hidden on Mac.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Why not make that single download simply ONLY install the files necessary for the version that will run on that OS, and then clean up after itself by deleting the unused files that you want to be made invisible?

Comment: Mark the files for the MacOS "hidden", while append a "." in front of the folder for Windows files.

Comment: This will probably be a horrible experience for users on both platforms...

Answer (score 0):

You can hide files/folders in Mac just by prefixing the filename with a dot (`.filename`) which will remain visible in Windows, so if you named the Windows files with a leading dot, you'd have that covered.  OS X also supports an 'invisible' attribute, which, given that it's not recognized by Windows, would most likely hide the Windows files from OS X while leaving them visible to Windows...but this would likely have to be set from OS X.  The reverse is a bit more tricky if you're working from OS X, but [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/22111/how-to-hide-files-from-windows-on-mac-os-x) got a couple of suggestions for how to do this.  Otherwise, if you just set the 'hidden' attribute in Windows, OS X should just ignore it.  You could then set this attribute for the Mac files, which would hide them from Windows.