# Is it possible to have a file hidden in Windows, but visible in OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, mac

Essentially, I am trying to have a thumb drive with two versions of a piece of software, one Windows executable, and one Mac executable. I want the Mac file hidden in Windows, and vice versa. I found that I could use SetFile and make a file invisible, which Windows will ignore. However, it seems Mac does not ignore the hidden attribute for Windows. This is a problem for my use case. Is there any way to achieve my goal? I am open to different file systems (NTFS, fat32, UDF, ISO9660/Joliet, etc)

[Making a file hidden in OS X but visible in Windows, and vice versa](https://superuser.com/questions/453917/making-a-file-hidden-in-os-x-but-visible-in-windows-and-vice-versa)

This suggests just marking the file as hidden in Windows, but it seems that the flag is now obeyed by OS X.

Comment: not even vaguely an answer… but I've seen a lot of structure that just use a resources folder, cross-platform, then 2 more labelled simply 'Mac' & 'Windows'. It used to be easier on CD/DVD ;)

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but it's always been possible to make CD-ROMs with a hybrid filesystem that presents as ISO9660 to Windows, and HFS+ to Macs. I imagine it would work fine even if the medium is a flash drive instead of an optical disk. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_disc

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use [hdiutil's makehybrid option](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) to create a hybrid HFS/ISO disk image, with the Mac files hidden in the ISO filesystem, and the Windows files hidden in the HFS filesystem. Here's an example from [an earlier stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781214/create-hybrid-mac-and-windows-iso-with-custom-main-folder-settings):

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o image.iso source_folder -iso -hfs -hide-iso cd_folder/application.app -hide-hfs "{cd_folder/application.exe,cd_folder/autorun.inf}"
```

I haven't tested this, but I think that in order to get the hybrid structure onto the thumb drive intact, you'll need to mount the image, *un*mount (but not eject) the thumb drive, and then use `dd` to copy the raw data to the actual disk (I'm pretty sure you need to use the /dec/rdisk# entries, *not* the ones with the s# suffix).

Comment: I tried this and was excited when the drive mounted correctly in OS X. Windows however is not seeing the ISO partition, and is complaining that the drive needs to be formatted :\ I tried to dd from the iso image itself, and by mounting the disk and using the rdisk dev node. Both gave me the same result...

Comment: Could the problem be that my image is not the same size as the media?